# Suppose that both $\{\operatorname{Arg}(z_n)\}$ and $\{\lvert z_n\rvert\}$ converge. Does $\{z_n\}$ converge?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose that both ${\operatorname{Arg}(z_n)}$ and ${\lvert z_n\rvert}$ converge. Does ${z_n}$ converge?

I have proved by using the sequential criterion of continuity in the metric space. We know, $z=\lvert z\rvert e^{i\cdot \operatorname{Arg}(z)}$ this is a continuous function hence $z_n$ converges. Am I right? Please explain. I am not confident in this argument. I am not able to find counterexamples. If the statement is true, how do I prove it using the $\epsilon$ definition of convergence?

Comment: Using the third point $|z|e^{i\mathrm{Arg}\,z_n}$, one gets $$|z_n-z|\leqslant|z|\,|\mathrm{Arg}\,z_n-\mathrm{Arg}\,z|+||z|-|z_n||$$

Comment: Did you try to use the third point I mention explicitely? Did you draw a diagram of these three points in the complex plane?

Comment: I Got the intermediate steps.